# Appending an element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var main_div = $('div[class^="select"]');  
var download_button = document.createElement('a');

download_button.setAttribute("id", "download");
download_button.style.color = "blue";
download_button.href = "#";
download_button.innerHTML = "Download";

main_div.append(download_button);
```

Nothing Happens , no new element is appended  to select what is wrong with this?

Comment: can you share your html? may be you are going wrong with the selector

Comment: check your console log

Comment: Also its funny when users mix js and jquery...

Comment: no it is right i have checkd it with `alert`

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j93ypx5r/2/ but [this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j93ypx5r/3/) won't work

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
main_div.append(download_button);
```

Instead of

```
main_div.appendTo(download_button);
```

**Update -**

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/fnbdffqa/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in jQuery like this:

```
 var main_div = $('div[class^="select"]'); 

 $("<a/>")
   .attr("id","download")
   .css("color","blue")
   .attr("href","#")
   .html("Download")
   .appendTo(main_div);
```

Comment: Accepted that you can do alot more with jquery chaining but not really needed here.

Comment: @Pilot What is the title to the question again? Maybe I am lost.

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix jQuery and JS like you did...

```
var main_div = $('div.select');  
var download_button = $('<a id="download" style="color:blue;" href="#">Download</a>');

main_div.append(download_button);
```